# Webscraping columns from wikipedia table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to get the Bowler and Team columns from the following wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bowlers_who_have_taken_300_or_more_wickets_in_Test_cricket

Able to get the bowler column with my code but team column proving difficult. Might be one for the cricket fans out there but any help is most welcome!

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bowlers_who_have_taken_300_or_more_wickets_in_Test_cricket"
website_url = requests.get(wiki).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, "lxml")

my_table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable plainrowheaders"})



bowler = []
team = []

for row in my_table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    bowler_cell = row.find_all("a")[0]
    bowler.append(bowler_cell.text)
print(bowler)
for row in my_table.find_all("td"):
    team_cell = row.find_all("a")[0]
    team.append(team_cell.text)
print(team)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go  -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bowlers_who_have_taken_300_or_more_wickets_in_Test_cricket"
website_url = requests.get(wiki).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, "lxml")

my_table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable plainrowheaders"})


i=0
bowler = []
team = []

x = my_table.select('a[title]')

while i < len(x):
    if i < 11:
        i=i+1
        pass
    else :
        bowler.append(x[i].text)
        team.append(x[i+1].text)
        i = i+2 
print(bowler)
print(team)
```

Comment: Thanks - it does. Would like to still find solution to being able to scrape the team column independently (even just for my own learning) if you or anyone else knows.

Comment: the second code handles specifically what you asked for.

Comment: Interesting to see a different method but it does - thank you!